# Loading multiple CSS files with single http request

Tags: css, http, yahoo

When I view the source code of yahoo mail, I see multiple css files in a `link` tag using an `&` symbol as shown below:

```
href="http://mail.yimg.com/zz/combo?kx/ucs/uh/css/271/yunivhead-min.css&kx/ucs/uh/css/221/logo-min.css&kx/ucs/avatar/css/17/avatar-min.css"
```

Does anyone know, how they separate each file and load them all using a single http request?

Comment: For more details about combo handler, pls Go to [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.YUILoader.html#property_comboBase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, there seems to be a script that joins the css files into a single response.

The path to the script is `http://mail.yimg.com/zz/combo`. It accepts several parameters containing paths to CSS files, which will then be joined and possibly minified.

If you play around with the URL, you can see that you could remove the `-min`-Prefixes from the URL and you get the unminified CSS file in return: http://mail.yimg.com/zz/combo?kx/ucs/uh/css/271/yunivhead.css&kx/ucs/uh/css/221/logo.css&kx/ucs/avatar/css/17/avatar.css

There are several CSS minifiers around, for example [CSSmin](http://code.google.com/p/cssmin/). But as this is a Yahoo page, they probably use their own CSS compressor, [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/). For details about how it works, see http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/#work.

Comment: Thanks. As everyone pointed out that '**Combo**' is the key, I googled for 'Combo and YUI' and found something useful [Here](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/07/16/combohandler/). As suggested by you and @skotos, YUI loader has been used.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with the specifics, but the URL looks like a query string with the CSS files as unnamed parameters.

http://mail.yimg.com/zz/combo will be a service that loads the CSS, then concatenates and probably minifies the files before serving back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that http://mail.yimg.com/zz/combo is a small program / script which collects all params (like kx/ucs/uh/css/271/yunivhead-min.css, kx/ucs/uh/css/221/logo-min.css, kx/ucs/avatar/css/17/avatar-min.css), bundles them and minimizes them.

This is similar to the bundling feature for MVC, which you can read about at http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-bundling-and-minification (or other sources).

Answer (score 0):

If you take the URL apart what you see is that it's a request to something called "combo" passing in various querystring keys (note there's no values) that are the paths to some CSS files.

These keys will then be extracted in the standard way given the server side language being used and the CSS for that url parsed into a variable before being returned in its entirety to the response.

Answer (score 0):

For their yui project, yahoo development have a project called yuiloader.  While designed primarily for yui, the code seems like it can be set up to serve other files as well.  This does more than COMBO.  it also works out dependancies. with JS and CSS.
As Yahoo is the Y in YUI, this is probably their code base for mail.yimg.com.
The code can be found on https://github.com/yui/phploader.